# Awesomium.net c# accessviolation exception

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm reading that the application should be build "thread"-safe with Awesomium.net (C#)
I'm calling the webView.executeJavascript("") method.. which sometimes crashes with the accessviolation exception.. Probably because it's not thread safe.
But I don't know how to make this work. An example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a thread-safe wrapper for Awesomium. Check out the source code of the class called `Browser` of [that project](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/ThreadSafeAwesomium.Net).

It will give you an idea on how to use Awesomium cross-threaded.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "thread safe"?

All calls to Awesomium must be performed from the same thread — UI thread or separate thread (using SynchronizationContext) http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/synchronization-model.html in non UI environment. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23253942/964478